# MATLAB: How to declare LMIs variable in LMILAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I need to implement a H_infinity control. But, I don't known how to declare the variable gama^2.

This is my problem:

```
min gama
s.t
|   P       *         *     *  |
|   0     gama^2I     *     *  | > 0
| AZ+BL     E       Z+Z'-G  *  | 
| CZ+DL     F        0      I  |
```

where A,...G are know matrices, I is a identity matrix and P,Z,L are unknow matrices.

This is my code:

```
  setlmis([]);

  gama = lmivar(1,[1 1]); 
  Z = lmivar(2,[n,n]);
  L = lmivar(2,[m,n]);
  P = lmivar(1,[n,1]);

  %%------------------

  YRL = -newlmi;

  lmiterm([YRL 1 1 P],1,1);            % term P
  lmiterm([YRL 2 1 0],0);              % term 0
  >> lmiterm([YRL 2 2 0],gamaI);          % term gama2I ????
  lmiterm([YRL 3 1 Z],A,1);            % term AZ
     lmiterm([YRL 3 1 L],B,1);         % term BL
  lmiterm([YRL 3 2 0],E(:,:,i));       % term E
  lmiterm([YRL 3 3 Z],1,1,'s');        % term Z + Z'
     lmiterm([YRL 3 3 0],G);           % term G
  lmiterm([YRL 4 1 Z],FC,1);           % term CZ
    lmiterm([YRL 4 1 L],D,1)           % term DL
  lmiterm([YRL 4 2 0],F);              % term F
  lmiterm([YRL 4 3 0],0);              % term 0
  lmiterm([YRL 4 4 0],I);              % term I

  %%------------------

  LMISYS = getlmis;

  nsis = decnbr(LMISYS); 
  c = zeros(nsis,1);

  for j = 1:nsis
      gamaj  = defcx(LMISYS,j,gama);
      c(j) = gamaj;
  end

  options = [1e-6 0 0 0 0];
  [copt,xopt] = mincx(LMISYS,c);

  gama_sol = c'*xopt

  K = L_sol * inv(Z_sol)
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gama^2I` is a scalar block of some size `k`, so it should be declared as

```
GAMMA2I= lmivar(1,[k 0]);
```

Please also note that the code

```
lmiterm([YRL 2 2 0],gamaI);
```

is wrong. The `0` in `[YRL 2 2 0]` means that the term is constant. The correct code is

```
lmiterm([YRL 2 2 GAMMA2I],1,1);
```

Comment: Can I declare `GAMMA2I= lmivar(1,[k 0]);` when I want to minimize only gama?

Comment: You have to do it anyway

Comment: My doubt is whether MATLAB understands this relationship between `gama` and `gama^2`. The optimization problem in my code is right?

Comment: Matlab should not know anything about `gama`. The optimization variable is `gama^2`, otherwise the matrix inequalities will not be linear.

Comment: But, Is possible to solver the optimization problem for minimize `gama`? I was thinking of rewriting the LMIs in terms of `gama` instead of `gama^2`, using the tranformation `S * LMIs * S'`. However, I don't known how to determine the matrix S.

Comment: You don't need to do this. The function `y=x^2` is monotonically increasing on [0,+inf], so the minimum `gama` is equal to the square root of the minimun `gama^2`. You can just calculate the `gama^2` and use the `sqrt` function.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much for answering to my doubts.